# any idea how gnash is doing?

Tags: project, status, gnash

For those who don't know [GNASH](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) is an open source flash movie player. It can also run as a browser plugin. However I don't know its cross-browser support. I think it only supports firefox and the konqurer web browsers so far. Just want to know if people have started using the product, what their experience was so far using it, etc.

Comment: Unless you want to ask a question about the _code_ for GNASH, I don't see how this fits the SO criteria. It looks like an advert for the product to me. For what it's worth, I installed it under Ubuntu10 and it choked on about the third Flash movie that I tried to get to. So it was ditched pretty quickly. I'm all for free software but not when it doesn't work.

Comment: Considering the release of HTML5 that includes standard support for H.264 and WebM video built-in, there won't be much need for an open source Flash video player very soon.

Comment: I really doubt that flash will die in the foreseeable future, given the immense power of the Adobe marketing machine... I'd like to see the flash-free future, but it won't happening any time soon, so gnash is still a very important project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using it in Google Chrome and it works great. The development is ongoing, but the progress is not that fast. I hope it will continue to evolve until it becomes a viable flash replacement, which will happen at the point it starts playing flash 10 videos...